# What is the default icon set in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: qt, icon-themes

I would like my Qt configuration to match the default Ubuntu 16.04 style.

What is the default icon set from the below list of icon sets?

[image]

Comment: Isn't easier to make Qt detect the used theme?

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: [Themes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications#Theme_engines) seems to not include the icon set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ambiance GTK is the default theme and Ubuntu Mono (dark) is the default iconset

([Ubuntu tweak tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/unity-tweak-tool) can be used to change it if you want to match *Ubuntu* with your QT)

Comment: The `Humanity*`, `LoginIcons`, `Suru` and `Ubuntu-Mobile` seem to be exact copies, why?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju good question :-) you got me there... might be due to  convergence? Canonical tossed them together so a mobile device can still work (but picks the U-M set) with the same Ubuntu download.

Answer (score 5):

Using the Unity Tweak Tool, I have found out that the default icon theme for Ubuntu 16.04 is Ubuntu-mono-dark.